# Access a variable in VF page from Controller without using get set method

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I have a visual force page as below:

```
<apex:page standardController="Interview__c" extensions="SkillReviewExtension">

  <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock title="Candidate Skill Evaluation" id="skills_list">

<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>



      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! SkillReview }" var="ct" >

       <apex:column value="{! ct.Skill__c}"/>
       <apex:column headerValue="Level">

        <apex:selectList value="{!Level1}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!isEditMode}">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
            </apex:selectList>

            <apex:outputText value="{!Level1}" label="You have selected:"/>       
</apex:column>

       <apex:column headerValue="Description"/>
       <apex:column headerValue="Comments">
       <apex:inputTextarea value="{!inputValue}" id="theTextInput" />
        </apex:column>

       </apex:pageBlockTable>


 </apex:pageBlock>


    </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

I have a controller extension as below:

```
public class SkillReviewExtension{

    private final Interview__c review;
    private boolean isEditMode;

public String Level1{get;set;}

 public SkillReviewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.review= (Interview__c)stdController.getRecord();

    }

    public List<Skill_Review__c> getSkillReview() {

        List<Skill_Review__c> results = [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c FROM Skill_Review__c where Interview__c =:review.id];

        return results;

    }


        public List<SelectOption> getCountriesOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> countryOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('1','1'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('2','2'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('3','3'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('4','4'));
        countryOptions.add(new SelectOption('5','5'));

        return countryOptions;
    }

    public String inputValue {get; set;}

    public PageReference save(){
        isEditMode=false;
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference edit(){
        isEditMode=true;
        return null;
    }  



}
```

I am trying to access the varibale named isEdit in my Visualforce page from controller. I can't do this by get and set method. How can the isEditMode variable can be accessed in rendered="isEditMode".

Comment: what is the reason, you can't make get set isEdit ?

Comment: Why can't you do by get and set method ?

Comment: When I use get and set method with this I get an error - Compile Error: Duplicate variable: isEditMode (attempt to re-create the variable with type: boolean) at line 47 column 20

Comment: I am trying to make the input fields and drop down in edit mode when I click edit button and when the VF is saved it should show the text only and not the dropdown or textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already did you job just need to modify isEditMode property

Just change `private boolean isEditMode;`

to public get set this will solve your problem

```
public  boolean isEditMode {get;private set;}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am able to access the variable , but when I click save and referesh the VF page the data I entered during edit is gone, it does not display. Any reason why is that?

Comment: @Rdvsm you are updating `isEditMode` to false in save method that is the reason..

Comment: I commented out the isEditMode in my save method, but now I loose the data I entered after I refresh the page. Any idea why?

Comment: @Rdvsm have you checked `inputValue ` in save method ?

Comment: @Rdvsm if this issue resolved then accept the ans which is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Am I right in thinking that you don't want to use get/set methods because you want the variable to be accessible but not settable?

If you change

```
private boolean isEditMode;
```

to

```
public boolean isEditMode {get; private set;}
```

then the variable will be accessible via {!isEditMode} but can only be changed via your save() and edit() methods.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to access the variable , but when I click save and referesh the VF page the data I entered during edit is gone, it does not display. Any reason why is that?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click save? When you refresh the page the data will be gone because you are not saving it or retrieving it from any records.

Comment: I would like to save the data I entered when it was in edit mode. How can I retain the data on the page.

Comment: You need to save it to a field on the object it relates to (e.g.)
    review.some_field__c = inputValue;
    update review;

Comment: I have a label called comments in my page . I do not have any corresponding object for it. In case I create one where should I place it in VF page? I have - <apex:outputText value="{!inputValue}" /> right now

Comment: Sorry for typo , I mean to say I do not have any custom field for the corresponding object where I want to save the comment. How should I go about it?