# Data disappear when page is refreshed

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension

I have a VF page where I have a input text and output text. I have the VF page in a page layout of an object called interview. I also have a separate edit/save button on the VF page. When I use edit on VF page and enter data and save it. I see the data on the page layout, but when I refresh the page the data goes away. How can I retain the data I entered in VF page even after I refresh the page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Interview__c" extensions="SkillReviewExtension">

  <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock title="Candidate Skill Evaluation" id="skills_list">

<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>



      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! SkillReview }" var="ct" >

       <apex:column value="{! ct.Skill__c}"/>
       <apex:column headerValue="Level">

        <apex:selectList value="{!Level1}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!isEditMode}">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
            </apex:selectList>

            <apex:outputText value="{!Level1}" label="You have selected:"/>       
</apex:column>

       <apex:column headerValue="Description"/>
       <apex:column headerValue="Comments">
       <apex:inputTextarea value="{!inputValue}" id="theTextInput" />
        </apex:column>

       </apex:pageBlockTable>


 </apex:pageBlock>


    </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class SkillReviewExtension{

    private final Interview__c review;
    public  boolean isEditMode {get;private set;}


public String Level1{get;set;}

List<skillReview> skillReview;


 public SkillReviewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.review= (Interview__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public List<Skill_Review__c> getSkillReview() {

        skillReview=new List<skillReview>();
        List<Skill_Review__c> results = [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c,Level__c FROM Skill_Review__c where Interview__c =:review.id ];

        return results;

    }



    public String inputValue {get; set;}

    public PageReference save(){
        isEditMode=false;
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference edit(){
        isEditMode=true;
        return null;
    }  





}
```

A little back ground: Skill Review object has skills, level (lookup) in it. On VF page the user enter the Level using drop down and when he clicks save it should actually record the level in the level object(lookup field) in the skill review object.

Comment: How are you "refreshing"? F5 or via code?

Comment: F5. I have this VF page in a page layout of a record. When I come back to the record the data I entered are gone.

Comment: Sometimes the URL doesn't reflect it when navigating, but you have to make sure that the URL contains the record id. Example: `http://xx.salesforce.com/apex/myPage?id=<myRecordID>`. That's why F5 is killing your data.

Comment: The URL does not change. It is the same all time. I am on the record and I click edit in my VF page to enter data. After I enter data and click save on VF page I can see the data. But if I refresh I do not see the data now. The URL i noticed is same and does not change.

Comment: What is that URL?

Comment: https://eas--recruit.cs51.my.salesforce.com/a0E4B000000RaVk

Comment: That's my point. What happened is that, when you clicked "Edit", you made a POST with the record ID to the new URL (which has not updated in your browser). By clicking refresh, you're not resending the parameters, leading to an empty page.

Comment: Sebastian is right. The page state is saved in ViewState rather than URL parameter.

Comment: How can I send the parameters in URL now?

Comment: Assuming you are using your controller from http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114326/access-a-variable-in-vf-page-from-controller-without-using-get-set-method , it's because your `save()` method doesn't do anything. You probably want to store `Level1` and `inputValue` on some record and save it.

Comment: The VF page is embedded in an iframe, you will not see the parent detail page changing its URL. The only way we can assist you in troubleshooting this is if you can show us the code in `SkillReviewExtension` so that we can see what members/variables your page elements are bound to and what you're doing with them in the `save()` method. I suspect that you're just not doing anything with the data that is in the controller extension variables and so they're not saved to the `Interview__c` record. If it looks like this [from your other question](/questions/114326/), that's exactly what's going on.

Comment: Please see the edit with some explanation of the object model. Level object is a lookup in Skill Review Object. Skill is an Object too.